# Qt PushButton + clicked() not always executing

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

After hours of debugging and searching for an answer on the web, I am a little bit in despair. This is my first small Qt project and what I try to do is the following: 
I want to build a little calculation game. It looks like this:
[Application before first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFuqN.png)
After clicking on "Check / New" there should be a change to the following: [Application after first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWHsk.png)

But often I do have to click on that button multiple times, to get it triggered. The "Quit" button works perfectly fine, so it does not seem to be a general problem, but probably shitty coding from my side.

Here is my code, I hope you have got some hints:

(1) mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int a, b, result;

private slots:
    void CmdCheckNewClicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

(2) mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <ctime>

void MainWindow::CmdCheckNewClicked() {

    if(result != -1) {
        int eingabe = ui->EdtInput->text().toInt();

        QString comment;
        if(eingabe==result) {
            comment = "Right";
        } else {
            comment = "Wrong";
        }

        comment += QString(": %1 + %2 = %3").arg(a).arg(b).arg(result);

        ui->LblComment->setText(comment);
        ui->EdtInput->setText("");
    }

    a = rand() % 20 + 20;
    b = rand() % 20 + 20;
    result = a + b;

    QString task = QString("%1 + %2").arg(a).arg(b);
    ui->LblTask->setText(task);

    ui->EdtInput->setFocus();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

        ui->setupUi(this);
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        connect(ui->CmdCheckNew, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                SLOT(CmdCheckNewClicked()));
        connect(ui->CmdQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(close()));
    }

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}
```

Also in the further course of use of that application, during submitting of results, that PushButton does not execute properly everytime. I really have no more ideas for further debugging.

Comment: How do you say not working "properly"? What is the expected result?

Comment: As I wrote above, it often takes me multiple clicks to get the button triggered and executing the clicked()-SIGNAL. This should then lead to the connected SLOT and trigger the function CmdCheckNewClicked().

But the other PushButton (the one to quit the application) does work fine. It always quits the application, every time I do click on it.

Comment: You are saying signal not emitting? Just replace method body of `CmdCheckNewClicked()` function by simple printf() or something to check that

Comment: I tried to do just put a simple QString into the LblTask Label by writing:
QString test = "test";
ui->LblTask->setText(test);

but it does not put anything into that label when executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when you change objects "created" directly in Ui the functions does not work properly. To check if that the case, place a `qDebug("here");` in the beggining of your SLOT  function. If the debug is triggered, the connection is not the problem, then the fastest solution would be create your Ui element in the MainWindow object.

Comment: Thanks so far, the qDebug statement is triggered everytime. So the Button works properly and it seems to be a problem with displaying the changes.

Could you give me a hint of what it means to create the Ui element in the MainWindow object?

Comment: Projects with advanced GUI is (usually) made in .h and .cpp, the .ui is nice to make a visual base to what you want to achieve. I do encourage you to take a deeper look into QML thou. 

To make it short, add a pointer of the item as private variable in the .h file, like : "QLabel *mLabel;" and in .cpp create it as: "mLabel = new QLabel(this);".. then take a deeper look into functions like "setGeometry" and so on... Qt has  a very good documentation of its objects.

Comment: That really helped a lot. I got it running, thank you very much! And thanks for the general information of how properly implement GUI functionality.